# How to get the y-axis value on press in Victoy area react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

[image]

Hey there.

From above image if i touch on a area i should get the y axis value from victory area.

I tried this as prop on VictoryArea component
`events={[{ target: 'data', eventHandlers: { onPressIn: (props) => { console.log(props); } } }]}`

I can not find it inside the props

Answer (score -1):

To get the y-axis value on press in Victory area chart in React Native, you can use the onPress event handler provided by Victory.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { VictoryArea } from "victory-native";

const Chart = () => {
  const [yValue, setYValue] = useState(null);

  const handlePress = (event, props) => {
    const { y } = props.datum;
    setYValue(y);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <VictoryArea
        data={[
          { x: 1, y: 2 },
          { x: 2, y: 3 },
          { x: 3, y: 5 },
          { x: 4, y: 4 },
          { x: 5, y: 7 },
        ]}
        onPress={handlePress}
      />
      {yValue && <Text>Y value on press: {yValue}</Text>}
    </>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: It always returns index 'all'

Comment: I am rendering VictoryArea inside VictoryChart.